# Matching Substrings in arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I'm looking for a little method that could check if the first *n* characters of string in the array are the same.

For example:

```
["Marseille", "Marsan", "Martin"].method(3) => true
["Mar", "Mar", "Mar"]
["Marseille", "Marsan", "Martin"].method(4) => false
["Mars", "Mars", "Mart"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shorter version would be using [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) with a block and [`Enumerable#one?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-one-3F):

```
class Array
  def same_prefix?(n)
    uniq{|x| x[0, n]}.one?
  end
end
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/C8Wv)

Comment: @CarySwoveland: it is a pure ruby solution, take a look at the link.

Comment: I was unaware of [Enumerable#one?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-one-3F). Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) to get prefix array:

```
["Marseille", "Marsan", "Martin"].map { |x| x[0,4] }
# => ["Mars", "Mars", "Mart"]
```

and [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-uniq) to remove duplicated items.

```
["Marseille", "Marsan", "Martin"].map { |x| x[0,4] }.uniq
# => ["Mars", "Mart"]
```

If all prefixes are same, result should be an array of single item.

---

```
class Array
  def same_prefix?(n)
    self.map { |x| x[0, n] }.uniq.size == 1
  end
end

["Marseille", "Marsan", "Martin"].same_prefix?(3)
# => true
["Marseille", "Marsan", "Martin"].same_prefix?(4)
# => false
```

Comment: Why would one add `:same_prefix?` after adding this method to an `Array`?

Comment: @Adobe, It was copied from irb session. I forgot to remove it. Thank you for pointing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Array
  def same_start?(n)
    start = first[0,n]
    all? { |e| e[0,n] == start }
  end
end

["Marseille", "Marsan", "Martian"].same_prefix?(3) #=> true
["Marseille", "Marsan", "Martian"].same_prefix?(4) #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to do this:

```
arr = ["Marseille", "Marsan", "Martin"]
n = 3
arr.each_cons(2).all? {|s1, s2| s1[0...n] == s2[0...n]}
#=> true
```

A slight variant can be:

```
arr.map{|s| s[0...n]}.each_cons(2).all? {|s1, s2| s1 == s2}
```